# Error: no taglibrary exists for that namespace

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, netbeans-7

I'm trying to use Netbeans to make a web application using facelets. I want to use Icefaces as my widgets. I get the following error message
Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components declared with prefix ace but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.

and the control fails to appear. I have a most simple file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"
xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
>
<head>
    <title>Shalom Elias</title>
</head>
<body>
<h:form id="form">
    Shalom
    <ace:dateTimeEntry id="date1" value="#{backing.date1}" renderAsPopup="true"/>
</h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

The web.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>welcome.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I think the taglibrary should be in icefaces-compat.jar which is available on what should be the class path. BTW, I used ace:, but ice: has exactly the same problem. Unfortunately, as a new user, I can't upload a snapshot of my directory structure but the jar files are located under web/WEB-INF/classes, which looks logical to me.

The question is: what is missing???

Thanks,
Ilan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the icefaces jar file in:

```
WEB-INF/lib
```

instead of WEB-INF/classes folder.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add these comments, but Netbeans decided to but the jar files inside the WEB-INF/classes. How do I tell it to use the lib directory? Now I get different error messages:    One or more resources have the target of 'head', but no 'head' component has been defined within the view.
    One or more resources have the target of 'body', but no 'body' component has been defined within the view.

Comment: For jsf you should use `h:head` instead of `head` and `h:body` instead of `body`. This is needed to correctly load the resources that facelets depend on.

Comment: Thanks Matt. At last some real progress! The h: indeed helped. Now when I finally know where the problem lies, I can go back and try to find what I can change in Netbeans so that it will be placed in lib instead of classes. Up until now I didn't know where the root of the problem was.

Comment: Did you accidently put the jar file in the source tree of your project (where your java files are)? It needs to go inside thi Library folder (right click on the Libraries node --> "Add jar")

Comment: No, and in fact I don't know how exactly Netbeans picked the classes folder. What I did do was use the new project wizard where I specified that I was jsf and inside jsf configuration I chose to use icefaces. It did its magic and I assumed it was doing the correct thing. Thanks to your help, I found out it is doing the wrong thing. How to tell it the right thing to do is my next problem - but a MUCH easier one now that I know what the problem is.

Comment: Matt,I just wanted to thank you again for your most welcome help. This morning I finally found the reason for the jar files ending up in the classes folder rather than in lib. I downloaded the icefaces binary code and the jars were arranged with the main jar files on the lib root as well as some others in subdirectories. I just copied the whole thing into the library. It was the subdirectories which were giving the trouble. This morning I removed the superfluous directory structure with all jar files at the same lib level and it put the jar files into the lib directory. Thanks again.

Comment: Good to hear that it works. Since you are new here please don't forget to mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: I would gladly mark your answer as accepted but I can't figure out how to do that. "Answer Your Question" is I answer my own question - so it isn't that.

Answer (score 0):

Put the **icefaces-ace.jar** file in:

`WEB-INF/lib`

instead of `WEB-INF/` classes folder.

And enjoy!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your answer slightly?